# Python re.sub How to replace every 0 in a string with a 2 when there is no 1 directly next to it?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am completely new to regex and now I have the following task:

I have a string that looks like that: `001000X00X001X00X`

Now i want to replace every 0 with a 2 when there is no 1 next to it that is not seperated by an X, so the example String should be changed to: `001000X22X001X22X`

I tried to use something like this, to do that:

```
s = re.sub(r'X0+X', 'X2+X', s);
```

so it searches for substrings that begin and end with an X and have a random number of '0's between but obviously every substring like that is being changed to 'X2+X'.
How can I count the number of 0s and replace every one of them with a 2?

Comment: What about `000X000`?

Comment: yeah you're right, that wouldn't even be covered by my code, but the solution from @mozway and @Wiktor Stribiżew both do that. ```000X000``` should be ```222X222```

Comment: Be aware, they really not do the same thing.

Comment: @lxg95 I wish you added a comment below my answer to provide feedback that your actual requirements differed from what you tried. I [updated my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68997043/3832970) to also handle cases when the zeros are either at the start or end of the string. Please let know if it works for you via a comment, and if not, please let know what is still not working.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am very new to regex, so i had to do some tryouts with your answer. I was able to solve my problem with @-mozway's answer, but i'm still grateful for your answer because i really want to improve my regex skills. I didn't know that there is another regex-module and i currently have a look at this stuff. I would have written a comment under your answer to say thanks, but stackoverflow asks their users to not spam the comment-sections with unnecessary posts that just say thank you.

Comment: So, `re.sub(r'(?<![^X])0+(?![^X])', lambda x: '2' * len(x.group()), s)` does not work for you? This is the real fix of my previous solution. Modifying `s` by appending `X`s on both ends is a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was too slow to provide a regex answer (@Wiktor Stribiżew, you're too fast!), so here is an alternative using the split string as intermediate:

```
'X'.join([re.sub('0', '2', i) if not '1' in i else i for i in s.split('X')])
```

If the string contains only 0/1/X, this would be a simpler/faster alternative:

```
'X'.join(['2'*len(i) if not '1' in i else i for i in s.split('X')])
```

*NB. following @JvdV's comment, here is a fix of @WiktorStribiżew 's answer:*

```
re.sub(r'(?<=X)0+(?=X)', lambda x: '2'*len(x.group()), 'X'+s+'X')[1:-1]
```

output: `'22X001000X22X001X22X'`

Comment: I think this might be more what OP is looking for since the other answer will discard leading or trailing groups of 0's while this one won't. e.g. `000X000` gets `222X222`. Though OP is not very clear about this requirement.

Comment: Btw, if you want to remove the `re.sub()` and not be relient on the regex module, maybe `'2'*len(i)` is a good alternative to `re.sub('0', '2', i)`

Comment: @JvdV yes this is correct, I kept it in case there are other characters, but I'll update the post

Comment: @JvdV I also provided a fix for the other answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
import re
s = '001000X00X001X00X'
print( re.sub(r'(?<=X)0+(?=X)', lambda x: '2' * len(x.group()), s) )
# => 001000X22X001X22X

## Or, if you also want to match start/end of string positions:
print( re.sub(r'(?<![^X])0+(?![^X])', lambda x: '2' * len(x.group()), s) )
# => 001000X22X001X22X
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/udyMur). *Details*:

- `(?<=X)0+(?=X)` matches one or more `0` chars when this chunk of text is immediately preceded and followed with an `X` char
- `(?<![^X])0+(?![^X])` - matches one or more `0` chars that are preceded with `X` or start of string and followed with `X` or end of string
- Once there is a match, the matched text is replaced with the same amount of `2` chars.

With the PyPi `regex` module (install in your terminal/console using `pip install regex`) you can use a more concise

```py
import regex
s = '00X00'
print( regex.sub(r'(?<=(?:^|X)0*)0(?=0*(?:X|$))', '2', s) )
# => 22X22
```

See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqtYwVZB3cAgwsBAnaugKDOvRAMioVdcmqRRpK5hb2OrYW8VVxOhaaClaaBhb2ugBeRH1KhoaqrrKKgbAYliTQVNrv//AQ) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0TbEhq/1).

The `(?<=(?:^|X)0*)0(?=0*(?:X|$))` regex matches

- `(?<=(?:^|X)0*)` - a location that is immediately preceded with either `X` or start of string and then zero or more `0` chars
- `0` - a zero
- `(?=0*(?:X|$))` - a location that is immediately followed with zero or more `0` chars and then either `X` or end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can match `X` followed by 1 or more times a zero ending with looking at an `X` to the right, and then replace all the zeroes with 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lpE9xP/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rLcbtv)

```
import re

pattern = r"X0+(?=X)"
s = "001000X00X001X00X"

print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group().replace('0', '2'), s))
```

Output

```
001000X22X001X22X
```

---

If you also want to match the zeroes at the start and at the end preceded or followed by `X`, start or end of the string:

```
(?:X0+|^0+)(?=X|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kl4g62/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Z2SOTa)

```
import re

strings = [
    "0X001000X00X001X00X0",
    "001000X00X001X00X",
    "000X000",
    "000"
]

pattern = r"(?:X0+|^0+)(?=X|$)"

for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group().replace('0', '2'), s))
```

Output

```
2X001000X22X001X22X2
001000X22X001X22X
222X222
222
```

Comment: I believe this is already in @WiktorStribiżew 's answer ;)

Comment: @mozway Ah he added it.

Comment: @mozway I have changed it to another variant.

Comment: As @JvdV pointed out, this does not work for cases like `s = "0X001000X00X001X00X0"`, see my answer for a fix ;)